# Remove last "." character/s from a string without removing in middle

Tags: java, string

I am reading a text file and create a excel file using it. I managed to do the conversion. But there is a description filed with one or two full-stop(.) that I wanna remove. Some times there may be have one full-stop, may be have two or may be no full-stop. I tried with using replace but it also remove the (.) inside/middle of the text. I don't wanna do that.

**These are some samples**

```
P/NO 9281195 . .                                 
TFR TO 202 . .                                                               
E/C 21118 GTLA/0267/0044505 NI                                                    
9259589 .PMGN JAYARATHNE .                       
GTLA/0267/0044505 662881724V .
```

**What I want is**

```
P/NO 9281195                              
TFR TO 202                                                            
E/C 21118 GTLA/0267/0044505 NI                                                    
9259589 .PMGN JAYARATHNE                
GTLA/0267/0044505 662881724V
```

Comment: What about a check like `if (line.endsWith("..") {...} else if (line.endsWith(".") {...}`? You could then remove the last characters of each line if necessary. You have to get every line as a `String` to do so, of course.

Comment: `line.replaceAll("(\s*\\.)+$", "")`.

Comment: @deHaar for real? Just remove the last char while it is equal to `.`.

Comment: @dbl Wouldn't that make some (unwanted) single dots stay in the file?

Comment: @deHaar of course not.. Still regex is much better in the case :) After the edit it seems that the string should be trimmed before each of the checks.

Comment: @dbl Sure, the regex is much better... Oh, haven't seen the need for trim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Solution :*

   You can use a regex that'll match some couple `(space point)` at the end, and replace this by nothing

   ```
   String line = "P/NO 9281195 . .";
   line = line.replaceAll("(\\s*\\.)+$", "");
   ```
2. *Details :*

   - `\s*` for 0 to unlimited space
   - `\.` for a point
   - `(\\s*\\.)+` for 1 to unlimited couples of space/point
   - `$` match at the end

Comment: Thankz....There also "," is coming at the end. *like : 9281195,,* I tried with **line.replaceAll("(\\s*\\.|\\,)+$", "")**, but it remove only one coma

Answer (score 3):

Try it

```
str.replaceAll("(\\.|\\s)+$", "")
```

This regex will match any `.` character or any space at the end of the line. So you just need to replace it with empty string.